Using os.Pipe for multiple shell commands
I want to run an equivalent to:
psql -lqt | cut -d \| -f 1 | grep -qw <dbName>; echo $?

So I'm trying to pipe the output of a command to the input of the next command and eventually read the output of the grep or the last exit value (I'm checking if a db with a specific name already exists).
I'm trying to concatenate a few bash commands using os.Pipe. When I'm trying to read the content of the the readers in the process, I see that the length of the byte slice passing through is 0. If I replace the writers with os.Stdout I see the correct output.
What am I doing wrong?
Relevant part of the code:
dbName := dbInfo["name"].(string)

reader1, writer1, _ := os.Pipe()
reader2, writer2, _ := os.Pipe()
var outBuff bytes.Buffer
//Each writer writes to its reader, they're connected through the pipe.

cmd1 := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "psql -lqt")
cmd1.Stdout = writer1

cmd2 := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", `cut -d \| -f 1`)
cmd2.Stdin = reader1
cmd2.Stdout = writer2

cmd3String := fmt.Sprintf(`grep -qw '%s'`, dbName)
cmd3 := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", cmd3String)
cmd3.Stdin = reader2
cmd3.Stderr = &outBuff //If a db doesn't exist I'm expecting an error.

go func() {
    err = cmd1.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Issue with running the command %s: %v\n",
            cmd1.String(), err)
    }
    writer1.Close()
}()
r1Info, _ := reader1.Stat()
content := make([]byte, r1Info.Size())
reader1.Read(content)
fmt.Printf("%s", content)

go func() {
    err = cmd2.Run()
    defer writer2.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Issue with running the command %s: %v\n",
            cmd2.String(), err)
    }
}()
r2Info, _ := reader2.Stat()
content = make([]byte, r2Info.Size())
reader2.Read(content)
fmt.Printf("%s", content)

go func() {
    err = cmd3.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Issue with running the command %s: %v\n",
            cmd3.String(), err)
    }
}()

exitVal := outBuff.String()
if len(exitVal) != 0 {

    //If the database doesn't exist, we create it.
    query := fmt.Sprintf(`CREATE DATABASE %s;`, dbName)

    _, err = dbPointer.Exec(query)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Couldn't run the query %s: %v\n", query, err)
    }
}


What is the actual problem? I mean, this code, simplified and fixed works OK, and if I stick back -q to the call to grep, it expectedly outputs nothing and exits with 0. I'm going to say it all works as expected, so what is the original, source problem you're trying to solve (please forget about those zero-length slices at the moment)?

@kostix When I used a wait group, closed the readers, took out the third command out of its goroutine and removed the escape from the "|" in cut, it worked.
Thank you very much for your simplified example!

Glad it helped! Please also consider that the use of bash is not only unnecessary but is a waste of resources and a potential landmine (as shell scripts need to be properly quoted). I mean, if you're assembing a process pipeline by hand, you basically recreating what the shell does using its | syntax.

While we're at it, note that as all the running processes are under the control of Go, we do not need OS-provided pipe and can use the "native" Go pipe like this. An upside is that less file descriptors will be used up; a downside is that your process will be woken up by the kernel to shovel the bytes between the processes in the pipeline. I'm not advocating using this approach; it's mostly shown for completeness.
